# Boolean check in Haskell when assigning IO action to variable

Tags: haskell, io, return, variable-assignment

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd like to be able to perform an IO action that returns a value, and if it gets assigned to a variable, then it suppresses a particular IO action (Or when, any action, I guess, it doesn't have to be an IO one).

Here's the specific issue I'm having:

When I do:

```
renderDrawable drawable
```

I want it to call a particular function (`drawArrays`).

When assigning to a variable, like:

```
d <- renderDrawable drawable
```

I want that particular function suppressed.

Now, this seems like a long shot, but is it possible? Something similar to mapM_/foldM_ would be ideal, I guess.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "supressed" ?

Comment: The closest you can get to this is to discriminate on the return type so that when returning `IO ()` you do something and when returning `IO TypeOfd` you do something else. This however would require a type class and even then may require some type annotation in the caller code. So, why don't you just define two different functions?

Comment: Perhaps describe in more detail what you're trying to achieve from a higher-level perspective. What you're asking for isn't possible in Haskell for good reasons, but there could be other, better ways.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for is possible in any other language either, it's just really bizarre, if I'm understanding it correctly...

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it was, but there've been a few things that have surprised me about Haskell's capabilities.

Essentially, what I wanted was an if statement to determine whether I call a function, based on how the original function is called, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

What you are asking for is impossible in Haskell.  One of the fundamental rules behind Haskell's design is [**compositionality**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_compositionality): the meaning of an expression depends exclusively on the meaning of its subexpressions and how they are combined.  The **only** exception is that the meaning of a variable depends on context.

What you're asking for, fundamentally, is to have `renderDrawable drawable` mean two different things depending on the context in which it appears in the program (in this case, depending on whether it's result is bound as a variable or not).  No can do.

Compositionality is intimately related with the principles of **referential transparency** and **purity** that Haskell's design also follows.  It's not just Haskell's design that values compositionality, too, because generally most programming languages obey it in most situations.  It's hard to reason about code otherwise.

The closest I can think of to what you're looking for is the contrast between this:

```
do {- ... -} 
   renderDrawable drawable
   {- ... -}
```

And this:

```
do {- ... -} 
   let d = renderDrawable drawable
   {- ... -}
```

If you're not familiar with this form of `let`, that's the way you assign a *pure value* to a variable inside of `do`-notation.  What you're doing here is you're taking `renderDrawable drawable`, and binding the **action itself** (not its result!) to the variable `d`.  This is just a variable assignment, so `renderDrawable drawable` is not executed.

Comment: Ah, I've never tried binding a function that returns an IO using a let before. I'm not sure I could use it, though. Since the result is the final state of something. If I pass `d` to it, it'd be an IO of the object, and then I'd need to bound it using a `<-` in the function anyway, meaning it'd recalculate the state every time it's called which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place. That's fine, I'll just have a bool argument or a separate function instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer probably isn't as good as above, since like they said, it's impossible, I've found another approach.

`drawDrawable` is a recursive function. `Drawable` is my data type, and so I added another node for `Drawable`. It took another `Drawable` as an argument, and also the current state which traverses down and simply sets a flag to true if I want it to render. So I'd have something like

```
drawDrawable Direct drawable
```

This seems like it could be a source for bugs, though. So I opted for separate functions: `compile` and `render`, where `render` returns an `IO ()` instead of `IO Drawable` as simply works like

```
render :: Drawable -> IO ()
render drawable = do
  cd <- compile drawable
  renderCompiled cd
```

Does the job and there's less ambiguity for the whole situation.